# Will this javascript function cause stack overflow

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

am trying to figure out if the following code will cause stack overflow or not, can someone please help

```
function testing() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        testing()
    },100 )
}

testing()
```

I am trying to use redis blpop command as an event queue and want to process the next message as soon as I am done with one

Comment: no, why should it?

Comment: because its an recursive function

Comment: It would cause stackoverflow if there was no setTimeout. With setTimeout, _before_ the next recusrsive call, previous call is popped off the stack; hence, the stack never fills up completely.